# android eclipse projects import open

Tags: android, eclipse, import, project

I am correct that if I have an existing project I have to IMPORT it back into eclipse?  I can not OPEN it?

Also, To remove project from eclipse I have been Deleting it.  Is that the correct way to close project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. You have to import the project to open it in an existing work space, and it's not necessary to delete project or remove it--you can just right click on the project and close it. You'll find the option when you right click.

Answer (score 0):

**Import the project**

If it is a valid eclipse project (has `.classpath` and `.projectpath`), you can re-import it back into eclipse. If the project is not in eclipse, you will also have to re-import again to work with it.

Use this to import: `File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace`

**Closing a project**

In eclipse, you can close a project using the project context menu. Right hand click on the project and select Close Project: `Right hand click -> Close Project`

**Deleting a Project**

There are two ways to delete a project in eclipse. The "soft delete" which does not remove the project files and the "hard delete" which remove the files from the system. The former requires you to select "Delete project files..." on the delete dialog that pops up.

Answer (score 0):

To Import:

click `File` -> `Import...` -> `Android` and select `Existing Android Code Into Workspace`

From there you choose the Root Directory for you Android project.

Instead of deleting the project:

Right click on the project and click `Close Project`

Comment: Similar problem here....But I cannot see an Android menu... I try to update Studio but I always get ""Unable to read repository at http://api.appcelerator.net/p/v1/release-download?token=A4pQanA0.
http://api.appcelerator.net/p/v1/release-download?token=A4pQanA0 is not a valid repository location.